# How to get rid of endless loop when loading HTML with carousel into an empty <div> in another HTML onload using jQuery $(document).ready(..)

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, bootstrap-4

I am learning HTML, CSS, Bootstrap 4, jQuery3 and JavaScript (ES6+) and created an exercise to practice and summarize.

I have 4 HTML files all have bootstrap 4 based responsive design:

- `index.html` contains Jumbotron, Grid System, Navbar, Modal Login.
- `main.html` contains 3-cards with images, title, some text, buttons and .
- `about.html` just contains the title "about".
- `contact.html` just contains the title "contact".

In `index.html`, the `Navbar` contains a logo and 3 items: About, Contact and modal for login. When clicking on "About" the `about.html` should load, when clicking on "Contact" then `contact.html` should load and when clicking on the logo the `main.html` should load. When clicking on "Login" the modal is shown. All this functionality is already working.

Now I want to complicate things a little and load `main.html` when the page initially loads using jQuery `$(document).ready(..)`.

When I add (uncomment) a call to `loadMainHtml()` in `script.js` the `main.html` is loading but it's blinking (refreshing??) and the carousel doesn't work. When I click the logo it all works great.

What am I doing wrong? I will appreciate any assistance.

Here are the HTML, CSS, and JS:

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="learning" content="Web Applications Development">
    <meta name="author" content="Binyamin (Benny) Regev">
    <title>Bootstrap + jQuery + AJAX Summary Exercise</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap: jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- Bootstrap: Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- local CSS and JavaScript links -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- Google Font - Beth Ellen-->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Beth Ellen' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat Brush' rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sofia' rel='stylesheet'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>

<body>
    <h1 class="h1-title">Bootstrap Summary Exercise</h1>
    <h4 class="h4-title">Jumbotron, Grid System, Cards, Navbar, Modal Login &amp; Responsive</h4>

    <!-- 
        Bootstrap Navigation Bar (Navbar) 
        Colored Navbar with Brand/Logo 
      -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
        <!-- 
            Will create humburger menu 
            button when width get narrow 
          -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_target">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <!-- 
            Open div, everythign inside it will be included 
            in the collapse menu under the Hamburger button 
          -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse_target">
            <!-- Brand/logo -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                Logo
                <img id="brand-logo" src="images/my_logo.jpg" alt="logo" style="width:40px;">
            </a>

            <!-- Links -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a id="menu-about" class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a id="menu-contact" class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link menu-item-login" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- The Modal Window -->
    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Register/Login Details</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="submitLoginRegister()">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sle_fullname">Full name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control_md" id="fullname" placeholder="Enter your full name"name="sle_fullname">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sle_email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control_md" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" name="sle_email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sle-pswd">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control_md" id="sle-pswd" placeholder="Enter password" name="sle_pswd">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sle-pswd2">Re-type Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control_md" id="sle-pswd2" placeholder="Re-type your password" name="sle_pswd2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="cbx_rememberMe"> Remember me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Login / Register</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Load HTML according to the clicked link -->
    <div id="loadHtml" class="load-html">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***main.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="course" content="Web App Dev - July 2019">
    <meta name="meeting" content="15 - jQuery"
    <meta name="author" content="Binyamin (Benny) Regev">
    <title>Bootstrap + jQuery + AJAX Summary Exercise</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap: jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->

    <!-- Bootstrap: Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- Google Font - Beth Ellen-->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Beth Ellen' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat Brush' rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sofia' rel='stylesheet'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>

<body>
    <!-- Bootstrap Jumbotron & jumbotron-fluid -->
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container jumbotron-container">
            <h1 class="display-3 h1-cat-book">Cat Book</h1>
            <p class="lead p-lead">Curiosity Killed The Cat</p>
            <hr class="my-2 d-none">
            <p class="d-none"></p>
            <p class="lead d-none">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="Jumbo action link" role="button">Jumbo action name</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap Grid System-->
    <div class="row card-deck">
        <!-- Bootstrap Card 1 of 3 -->
        <div class="card col-md-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                <img class="card-img-top img-circle mx-auto"
                    src="images/kitten-image.jpg"
                    alt="kitten">
                <h4 class="card-title text-center">Kittens</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                <p class="card-text">
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                    industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
                    and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                </p>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                    industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
                    and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                </p>
                <button type="button" class="btn mt-auto mx-auto btn-primary btn-lg d-block">Learn More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Bootstrap Card 2 of 3 -->
        <div class="card col-md-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                <img class="card-img-top img-circle mx-auto"
                    src="images/ninja-cat.jpg"
                    alt="ninja cat">
                    <h4 class="card-title text-center">Ninja Cats</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                <p class="card-text">
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                    industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
                    and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                </p>
                <button type="button" class="btn mt-auto mx-auto btn-primary btn-lg d-block">Learn More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Bootstrap Card 3 of 3 -->
        <div class="card col-md-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                <img class="card-img-top img-circle mx-auto"
                    src="images/hairless-cat.jpg"
                    alt="hairless cat">
                <h4 class="card-title text-center">Hairless cats</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                <p class="card-text">
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                    industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
                    and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                </p>
                <button type="button" class="btn mt-auto mx-auto btn-primary btn-lg d-block">Learn More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- The slideshow -->
        <div id="main-carousel" class="carousel-inner bg-dark">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <!-- Center the image in the Carousel -->
                <div class="parent d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <img class="center-block" src="images/img-dancing.jpg" alt="dancing">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Dancing</h3>
                        <p>In life she has blue eyes</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <!-- Center the image in the Carousel -->
                <div class="parent d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <img class="center-block" src="images/img-laying-back.jpg" alt="relaxing">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Relaxing</h3>
                        <p>Exactly as in real life!</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <!-- Center the image in the Carousel -->
                <div class="parent d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <img class="center-block" src="images/img-having-fun.jpg" alt="having fun">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Having Fun</h3>
                        <p>&#9892 Anyone want to lift the blanket? &#9940</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***about.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="course" content="Web App Dev - July 2019">
    <meta name="meeting" content="15 - jQuery">
    <meta name="author" content="Binyamin (Benny) Regev">
    <title>About HTML -- Bootstrap + jQuery + AJAX Summary Exercise</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap: jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap: Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- Google Font - Beth Ellen-->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Beth Ellen' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat Brush' rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sofia' rel='stylesheet'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="about-content">
    <header>
        <div>
            <h1>About</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>

    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

***contact.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="course" content="Web App Dev - July 2019">
    <meta name="meeting" content="15 - jQuery">
    <meta name="author" content="Binyamin (Benny) Regev">
    <title>Contact HTML -- Bootstrap + jQuery + AJAX Summary Exercise</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap: jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap: Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- Google Font - Beth Ellen-->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Beth Ellen' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat Brush' rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sofia' rel='stylesheet'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="contact-content">
    <header>
        <div>
            <h1>Contact</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>

    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

***style.css***

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=montserrat");
body {
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

.jumbotron-container {
    height: 200px;
}

.h1-cat-book {
    font-family: 'Beth Ellen';
    text-align: center;
}

.p-lead {
    font-family: 'Caveat Brush';
    text-align: center;
}

.row {
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.img-circle {
    width: 15em;
    height: 15em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.menu-item-login {
    font-family: 'Sofia';
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.h1-title, .h4-title {
    text-align: center;
}

.h1-title {
    font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;
    font-size: 5em;
}

.h4-title {}

.carousel-inner img {
    height: 400px;
}
```

***script.js***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#brand-logo").click(function() {
        /* load main.html */
        loadMainHtml();
    });

    $("#menu-about").click(function() {
        /* load about.html */
        loadAboutHtml();
    });

    $("#menu-contact").click(function() {
        /* load contact.html */
        loadContactHtml();
    });

    function loadMainHtml() {
        $("#loadHtml").load("main.html", function(strResponse, strStatus, xhr){
            if (strStatus == "error") {
                alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    }

    function loadAboutHtml() {
        $("#loadHtml").load("about.html", function(strResponse, strStatus, xhr){
            if (strStatus == "error") {
                alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    }

    function loadContactHtml() {
        $("#loadHtml").load("contact.html", function(strResponse, strStatus, xhr){
            if (strStatus == "error") {
                alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    }

    // Uncommenting the following code will make the page blink
    // loadMainHtml();
});
```

Using `$.get()` instead of `.load()` also gives the same result. Below is the code with `.get()` that I used to replace the call to `loadMainHtml()` in 
***script.js***:

```
/*  *************************************************
    Uncommenting any of the following code sections 
    will make the page to reload again and again
    ************************************************* */
/* Option 1: calling the same function that is used in
             clicking on the "Logo" he left-most item in 
             the top Navbar */
// loadMainHtml();

/* Option 2: using $.get(): */
// $.get("main.html", function(strResponse, strStatus, xhr) {
//     if (strStatus == "error") {
//         alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
//     } else {
//         // Display the returned data in browser
//         $("#loadHtml").html(strResponse);
//     }
// });

/* Option 3: Using $.ajax(): */
// $.ajax({
//     url: "main.html", 
//     success: function(result) {
//         $("#loadHtml").html(result);
//     }
// });
```

Comment: seems like an infinite loop.  load a page, that loads a script that loads a page, it will just keep refreshing.

Comment: I am a novice in HTML, CSS, JS, jQuery, and bootstrap - How can I resolve this? I tried using AJAX $.get() instead of `.load()` (see the changes in script.js) and got the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your sub pages all contain the javascript, so you're loading all you javascript again into the #loadHtml container and then executing it, loadMainHtml() is running in and infinate loop. Your sub pages should only contain the html fragments to be injected not an entirely formed html file.

In main.html you should strip out everything outside of the body tags as well as any unneeded css and javascript. Have a look in the element inspector of #loadHtml with your current script you'll see an entire html file loading into it and executing another copy of your script.js

after you've loaded in the content and placed in on the page any new components that require javascript need to be initialized in the callback. for example

```
// Activate Carousel
function loadMainHtml() {
    $("#loadHtml").load("main.html", function(strResponse, strStatus, xhr){
        if (strStatus == "error") {
            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
        }
        $("#myCarousel").carousel(); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. For me, when I added "$("#myCarousel").carousel();" the carousel 'jumped' 2 images, so I didn't use the call to ".carousel()".